# Dynamic forms - Auto fill fields based on previous auto complete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form with two fields `phone` and `name` what i want is when the user selects a phone number using ajax autocomplete the name field will be auto filled with the name that correspond to that phone number.

Watching that [Railscasts episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7yhPlIehFA) i was able to make ajax autocomplete works, any clean way of doing the auto filling?

patients_controller

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @patients = Patient.order(:phone).where('phone like ?', "%#{params[:term]}%")
   json_data = @patients.map(&:phone)
   render json: json_data
  end
end
```

reservations.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#patient_phone').autocomplete
  source: "/patients/index"
```

_form.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :patient, appointment.patient do |patient| %>
  <%= patient.text_field :phone, id: 'patient_phone' %>
  <%= patient.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: question is where do you put the phone-name relation?

Comment: question is how to auto fill the name that correspond to the selected phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to modify both:

The `index` action

```
def index
  @patients = Patient.order(:phone).where(
              'phone like ?', "%#{params[:term]}%")
  render :json => @patients.collect { 
                  |x| {:label => x.phone, 
                       :value => x.phone, 
                       :name => x.name} 
                      }.compact
end
```

The ajax request

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#patient_phone').autocomplete
  source: "/patients/index", messages: noResults: '', 
          results: func = -> ''
  select: (event, ui) -> $("#patient_name").val(ui.item.name)
  focus: (event, ui) -> $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").hide();
```

And add the id `patient_name`to the form field.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you build the relationship between name and phone number but you can auto fill name inside autocomplete `select` event like this

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#patient_phone').autocomplete
    source: "/patients/index"
    select: (event, ui) ->
      selected_phone_number = $(event.target).val()
      // Fill in value for name field here
```

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select